# Can I insert a string into a tkinter text box with a tag?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-text

I would like to insert text into my console text box in tkinter, but I would like to insert the text with a tag, instead of setting a tag afterwards. Is this possible? If not is there a better way to do this than what I am already doing?

**I tried this:**

```py
console.config(state="normal")
start = output.index(END)
console.insert(END, string)
end = output.index(END)
console.tag_add("err", start, end)
console.config(state="disabled")
```

But it did not completely work the way I wanted it to. It highlighted more text than I wanted with the `err` tag.

Comment: I don't see `prev_end` defined anywhere here

Comment: Thank you. That lets me insert the text, but I still don't know how to insert it with a tag.

Comment: Did you use `tag_configure` to create the style for the `err` tag prior to calling `tag_add`?

Comment: The Text widget's `.insert()` method takes an optional third parameter, which is a tuple of tags.

Comment: @jasonharper well that's good to know! Always learning something new around here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `insert` method accepts both text and tags. The first argument after the index is text to insert, the next argument is assumed to be a tag, the next is text, the next is a tag, etc.

The following example will insert the string at the end of the widget, and add the tag `err` to the inserted text.

```
console.insert(END, string, "err")
```

You can provide a single tag, or multiple tags in a tuple. The following example inserts text with the tags `err` and `critical`:

```
console.insert(END, string, ("err", "critical"))
```

The following example shows how you can insert multiple strings and multiple sets of tags in a single call to insert. It will insert the string "foobar", with "foo" getting the tag `red` and "bar" getting the tag `green`.

```
console.insert(END, "foo", "red", "bar", "green")
```